# Database mirroring - SQL Procedure call

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, mirroring

I have created a SSRS report (SQL Server 2005), however on running it I receive an error that a view doesn't exist on the mirrored database (I haven't dealt with mirroring before). What happens is I run the SQL stored procedure on the 1 database and it runs fine returning all the data expected. If I run the report pointing to the mirrored database, it picks up the stored procedure but not the view. If I go and look in enterprise explorer both the stored procedure and View don't exist in the database.

I'm convinced it's a mirroring issue, but I'm not sure how to get the view to the other database, and why doesn't the stored procedure show up under Enterprise explorer?

thanks.

Comment: get the report from the principal server, not mirrors

Answer (score 0):

Try sp_refreshview against the view on the mirrored database.